# JAVAFX, how to update maximized-Undecorated window's width and height on screen when taskbar's location gets changed?

Tags: javafx, controller, javafx-8

**What I am trying to do is this...**[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX9hL.gif)

**I am trying to add the ability for my Undecorated-window to automatically resize when its in maximize and the taskbar's location gets changed.**

I have gotten close by using a onMouseMove to detect the screen size change through getVisualBounds() and checking for that. A problem with onMouseMove() is it only resizes when the mouse is moved over the window and not after the taskbar has been changed.

Here is the Demo Code I came up with.

```
/////// controller Class////////
private Stage stage;
boolean lock = false;
ObservableList<Screen> screenSizes;

public void setUp(Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
        screenSizes  = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(this.stage.getX(), this.stage.getY(), this.stage.getWidth(), this.stage.getHeight()));
}


@FXML
protected void onMaximizedButton() {
        if(lock == true){
            stage.setMaximized(false);
            lock = false;
        }else{
            stage.setMaximized(true);
            lock = true;
            stage.setX(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getMinX());
            stage.setY(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getMinY());
            stage.setWidth(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getWidth());
            stage.setHeight(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getHeight());
        }


}

@FXML
private void onMouseMove(){
        ObservableList<Screen> newScreenSizes = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(),stage.getHeight()));
        if(!(newScreenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().equals(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds()))){
            if(lock == true){
                //stage.setMaximized(true);
                screenSizes = newScreenSizes;
                stage.setX(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getMinX());
                stage.setY(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getMinY());
                stage.setWidth(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getWidth());
                stage.setHeight(screenSizes.get(0).getVisualBounds().getHeight());

            }

        }

}
///// main class////////
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        HelloController helloController = fxmlLoader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();
        helloController.setUp(stage);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
}
```

I am asking if there is a way to get the taskbars' location and update it when it gets changed?

**Other things I have thought about but have not done, maybe use Observable list of Screens and add a listener to it and somehow bind it to something to have it auto change when taskbar gets changed?**

Comment: The _easiest_ solution I can think of is to repeatedly pool the screen's visual bounds, but to get the quick reaction you're looking for would require frequent polling which seems.... wasteful, to say the least. Another option is to see if you can watch for changes in the screen's visual bounds via native code (don't know if that's possible, don't know how easy it would be if it is).

Comment: *Almost* everything in JavaFX is observable either as a property or an observable list.  In the [Screen class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html), the list of screens is observable, but the screen bounds and visual bounds are not.  So, although you can listen to the screen list for addition and removal of screens, you can't add a listener to the screen bounds or visual bounds, as they are not properties.  I think you already know this, just adding extra context for others who may come across this question.

Comment: @Slaw yes, I have been trying to avoid doing a continuous updating of the screen's visual bounds. That does not seem good for performance. my demo code works to kind of simulate it but it does not fully act the same way. I have been trying to look for a solution natively in javafx

Comment: I also looked at JNA but it seems so complicated, for JNA you have to learn a lot about windows native libraries which is going to be very painful. I looked at some of it and the way windows names their variables and functions hurts my eyes.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe using reflections, on the library controlling the function for decorated style and add  the native ability to customize the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

May be this may not be a right solution, but if you are ready to take the risk of using com.sun.* classes, you can go with the below approach.

```
import com.sun.glass.ui.Screen;

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // Your code....

    Screen.setEventHandler(new Screen.EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleSettingsChanged() {
            System.out.println("Resize the window here......");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the risk with using com.sun? is it tightly coupling?

Comment: From the doc.. "Classes in com.sun.* and sun.* packages are considered implementation details, and are not part of the Java API. They can cause problems when moving to new versions of Java because there is no backwards compatibility guarantee. Such classes are almost always wrapped by Java API classes that should be used instead"

Comment: @TookLong As noted, the biggest risk is the private API/implementation changes or is removed entirely without notice, potentially breaking your application. Additionally, assuming you have JavaFX on the module-path (which you should), then a complication is needing an appropriate `--add-exports` JVM argument during compilation _and_ execution.

Comment: At this point, I keep running into problems just trying to design a custom title bar, so that I could color it blue. I think I am just gonna use decorated style, but redesign it and finish the project. Then i'll just move on and never use javafx again, its honestly so difficult just to do one simple thing.